# Get bullish trend from index

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stock

I need bullish trend from stock exchange data. Data is like

```
ticker   date         open        high       low        
AABS     2014-03-06   98.20       97.40      98.20      
AABS     2014-03-05   98.01       96.01      98.91      
AABS     2014-03-04   97.00       97.00      96.07      
AATM     2014-03-06   7.43        6.35       7.43       
AATM     2014-03-05   6.00        5.00       5.00          
AATM     2014-03-04   5.28        4.55       4.60      
AATM     2014-03-03   7.45        3.20       7.30
```

the solution which I require is, for each ticker and most recent date, check the trend for open, high and low, if they are increasing from previous dates, and increasing since how many days.
So the result set will be

```
ticker   date         opnTrend     highTrend   lowTrend  
AABS     2014-3-06    2            1           0         
AATM     2014-3-06    2            4           3
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I tried it using CTE (common table express) with recursion but could not figure out the way.